# Pick a color that is base of hair or skin

Tags: color-profile

Looking any hair or skin you notice different tones, shades, and so on... which is the base color that is determinant of such hair or skin? and that is the origin of all tones and shades of them? How to pick the correct basic color?

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. This one is difficult.

There are a lot of variables, but besides anatomical or physiological issues, like a sunburn zone.

In photography, there are different types of light, I would say that you need to use a spot:

- Well lit.
- Not a highlight.
- Not on a shadow.
- Not shiny, not oily skin zone.

---

I would differentiate several aspects from color.

Hue, lightness, saturation.

This spot will give you a base hue, and a base saturation, but the lightness is the one most likely will change across different shades of light. Keep that in mind.

The hue will change a bit from yellow-ish to red-ish, regardless of the skin tone.

Answer (score 1):

From a photo with the following characteristics:

[image: Clean portrait]**Clean portrait**

[image: Daylight] **Daylight picture**

[image: Neutral] **Neutral light**

[image: sun] **No direct sun**

[image: artificial] **No artificial illumination**

[image: retouched] **No retouched or levels adjustments**

[image: shadows] **Without projected shadows**

[image: resolution] **Good resolution**

Applying a **Mosaic Photoshop Effect**, the options of possible colors are reduced facilitating the search of an average tonality.

Avoid picking a color from:

- The middle of the forehead, nose or cheeks that are usually where there's a higher light incidence
- Own shadows such as the tones of the face contour, under the nose or lips, the eyelids, under the chin or neck.

[image: Face01]

[image: Face02]

[image: Face03]

[image: Face04]

[image: Face05]

[image: Face06]

[image: Face07]

Photos from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/search/photos/portrait): "Portrait pictures"

Answer (score 0):

Skin and hair are complex multilayer structures and their apparent color can vary drastically when the angle of light and watching direction are changed. In addition there's different lights and one can radically alter the surface by adding a little some powder or oil. Finally combing the hair changes its local density and direction. The skin is partially seen through a sparse hair.

I think you have seen how a strong, a little oily dark hair shines. It's as far away from single color matte paper as a rainbow and shimmering sea together.

If we assume there's no shiny effects, the the resolution of the image is so low that individual hairs or skin surface structure cannot be seen and the light is diffuse white having some standard brightness, there's still variation due the material and pigment differences. The amount of the pigment varies in one person's hair widely and the watching direction affects how thickly it's seen.

I do not believe there's a standard skin color or standard hair color from which all variations based on pigment and material differences can be derived with some simple transformation rule which need less knowledge than the wanted final color.

If you want to build some hair or skin color palette from where the effect of the light brightness is eliminated and you have properly white balanced photos as your raw material, you can use the following workflow

1. Convert your photo to Lab color mode in Photoshop
2. Select a non-shiny and non under or over exposed area of skin or hair in the photo, make a selection
3. Goto Filter > Blur > Average
4. Take a sample with color picker. Step 3 isn't needed if you use big enough sampling radius in the picker.

Lab color system allows changing the L-channel (=lightness) without changing the color hue and vice versa. This separates the color of the material from the amount of light.

Numbers a and b contain your hue and saturation and L is the lightness. Ratio b/a (or a/b) can be considered more basic, it's the hue only. NOTE: Division by zero is not acceptable, better is to make polar transformation from rectangular coordinates (a,b) and use the vector angle as hue. That's realized in HCL color system. More math is unfortunately out of my possiblities.

If you use GIMP instead of Photoshop, you can use  HCL colors. It's a more intuitive variation of Lab. It presents a and b as Chroma and Hue.

Warning: Both Lab and HCL produce easily colors which are out of the color range of the monitors. Learn, how to reveal them. GIMP has funny purple warning markers and in Photoshop you can switch Gamut warning ON and use sRGB proof color in Lab mode.

**I tested this story** a little (only one photo, surely not under- or overexposed, taken outdoors in a cloudy day as RAW)

[image]

In the right there's the photo seen normally. In the left it's in Lab color mode and the Lightness channel is turned off. We can see strong saturation and hue variations. Hue variations are caused by the skin which is seen through. But the saturation variations can be in the hair or the watching direction affects. More tests are needed.

We turn the L channel ON again, but equalize the lightness with a grey layer with blending mode Luminosity. We equalize the saturation with a solid color layer with blending mode Saturation The color was sampled from a place where the saturation in the hair is strong. We get:

[image]

Now it's obvious in which parts the skin color affects also to hair color. We sample the hair in a thick place and the skin and make the card for the person:

[image]

The left part has her hair hue and the right part has her skin hue. All variations that we can see are saturation and luminosity differences. But the ratio of a and b in Lab color system are characteristical for that person (or actually for that person + the camera + the gray reference used in developing the RAW + the cloudy day + surrounding colored objects + color profile errors in my computer equipment & software)

BTW. I had proof colors and gamut warning ON. Proof color in use = sRGB

[image]